# How to handle two-phase commit with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a two-phase commit using SQLalchemy 0.6.8 with Postgresql 8.3.4, but I think I'm missing something...
The workflow goes like this:

```
session = sessionmaker(engine)(autocommit=True)
tx = session.connection().begin_twophase(xid) # Doesn't issue any SQL
session.begin()
session.add(obj1)
session.flush()
tx.prepare()
```

then from another session

```
session = sessionmaker(engine)(autocommit=True)
session.connection().commit_prepared(xid, recover=True) # recover=True because otherwise it complains that you can't issue a COMMIT PREPARED from inside a transaction
```

This doesn't raise any error, but doesn't write anything to the table either... O_o
What am I missing?

I tried even blocking the application after the `prepare()` and issuing a `COMMIT PREPARED 'xid'` from pgadmin, but still nothing gets written.

Comment: How is a two phase session supposed to work if you are flushing and autocommitting? Also, sessions use transactions internally. Are you using two different abstraction levels?

Comment: If I disable autocommit, the call to connection() issues a "BEGIN (implicit)" and then the begin_twophase raises a "Cannot start a two phase transaction when a transaction is already in progress."... I'll try skipping the flush though

Comment: Skipping the flush doesn't change anything :( Should I use sessionmaker(twophase=True) ?

Comment: Have you tried using a different variable name for each session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get it working, here's how:

```
session = sessionmaker(engine)(twophase=True)
session.add(obj1)
session.prepare()
# Find transaction id
for k, v in s.transaction._connections.iteritems():
   if isinstance(k, Connection):
      return v[1].xid
```

then from another session

```
session = sessionmaker(engine)(twophase=True)
session.connection().commit_prepared(xid, recover=True)
```

Comment: still idont understand for a single  database why you are using 2PC ?

Comment: @zabusa IIRC I had to ensure things were consistent between the pgsql instance and another database... It's been 10 years :D

Comment: oops.sorry my mistake ..